# Android app open gpx files

Tags: android, mime-types, intentfilter, gpx

I have build an app to edit gpx files on Android. Now I want to register my app to handle gpx files.

Therefor I have build some intent-filters. These filters are working sometimes, but not often. I can open gpx files, that I have received via Inbox, but no files from Gmail. Files from Dropbox are sometimes working.

Can anyone help me, to improve my intent filters, so that they are working every time my user trys to open a gpx file?

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/gpx+xml" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx" />
        </intent-filter>
```

EDIT:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/gpx+xml" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Support the `content` scheme, with the MIME type (since `pathPattern` is meaningless with `content` `Uri` values).

Comment: I have added the code you can see in my question above. But it is still not working @CommonsWare

Comment: You should be able to remove the `android:host`, as that should not be needed here. However, please understand that you will not get 100% success. You have no choice but to rely on other applications knowing the proper MIME type, and you have no control over those other applications to ensure that they always know the proper MIME type.

Comment: Okay, many thanks. I'll give it a try.